# How to update UserManager in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Good day,

I created and assign a user with password in asp.net Identity 2.0 MVC5 (and am barely new at it) and upon login; I directed the user to create (update) his/her account.

All went well but when the user submit the updates, it doesn't reflect inside the database. It seems am missing out the right logic in my code. Here is my ViewModel and Controller.

please, I need your help.

```
    public class EditUserViewModel
        {
            [Key]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Surname")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Username")]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Gender")]
            public string Gender { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

            //[Required]
            [Display(Name = "Birthday - yyyy/mm/dd")]
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            //public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
        }


    Controller:
    [HttpGet, ActionName("profile")]
            public ActionResult Edit()
            {

                return  View();
            }

            [HttpPost, ActionName("profile")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel editUser)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid && TempData["Username"] != null)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(editUser.Username);

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound(); //change error later
                    }
                    user.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = editUser.LastName;
                    user.UserName = editUser.Email;
                    user.Email = editUser.Email;
                    user.PasswordHash = editUser.Password;


                    var userUpdated = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                    if (!userUpdated.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", userUpdated.Errors.First());
                        return View();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "pages");
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed!!!");
                return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use user.PasswordHash as that is set specifically by the UserManager. You will need to generate a Password reset token to reset the uesrs password, something like this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("profile")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel editUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && TempData["Username"] != null)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(TempData["Username"] as string);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound(); //change error later
        }

        user.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
        user.LastName = editUser.LastName;
        user.UserName = editUser.Email;
        user.Email = editUser.Email;

        var userUpdated = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(editUser.Password))
        {
            UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new EmailTokenProvider<IdentityUser>();
            var resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, resetToken, editUser.Password);
        }

        if (!userUpdated.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", userUpdated.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("index", "pages");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed!!!");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bobby Caldwell. I missed the password out. Yet the error I got while debugging states var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(editUser.Username) is null.

Comment: Ah I see, so the user may not have been created yet. Instead of throwing an error, should you just create a new user? I will update my answer to reflect adding a new user if one is not found.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to direct User after they login to a page where they can update their profile (firstname, lastname,username, password etc) as against the username and password I gave them to use.

Comment: Is editUser.Username an empty or null string? That could be why the UserManager is not finding the user. Maybe try TempData["Username"] as string